# Waves 360 bundle only works in stereo in Adobe Audition

Tags: sound-design, mixing, sound-effects, upmixing

My question: Why do the waves360 plugins work only in stereo mode in Adobe Audition CC? I add them to the 5.1 channels. I have a 5.1 speaker system for monitoring when mixing. Waves Um226 and s360 imager - sum R, L + LsRs and the central speaker is ignored. As if downmix is happening. Standard Track panner Audition with all the speakers works fine.

[image]

Effects routing works only in stereo. 
[image]

But when I add Waves m360 manager to the master channel, this plugin works fine on the master channel. What am I doing wrong? Please, help!

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is - this sounds like it's working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what the issue is: I haven't been working with surround sound too often, but the only reason, that I can think of, is that your sound card can't monitor 5.1...
Did you have surround sound working on your system before?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It turned out all much easier: I added plug-ins to 5.1 track, or to bus 5.1, and not to stereo. And the plugins work.